# Filter after 'null' column values in the shipment grid issue on Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent

I've added a new column to the shipments grid: `email_sent`, by creating this file:

```
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_shipment_grid.xml
```

and this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
        <column name="email_sent" class="VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\EmailSent">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\EmailSent</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email Sent</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

In the VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\EmailSent I have this code:

```
class EmailSent implements ArrayInterface
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' =>  1, 'label' => __('Sent')],
            ['value' =>  0, 'label' => __('Not Sent')]
        ];
    }
}
```

Filtering after `Sent` values is working, but filtering after `Not sent` are not. The `sent_email` contains `NULL` or `1` values. It is default Magento.
I tried different scenarious, like:

```
['value' =>  '', 'label' => __('Not Sent')]
```

or

```
['value' =>  null, 'label' => __('Not Sent')]
```

But it s not working.
[image]

**Other info:**

In my di.xml from `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Adds additional data to the shipment grid collection -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="vendorName_shipment_grid_collection" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\AddDataToShipmentsGrid" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and in the AddDataToShipmentsGrid class I have this to get the values of `email_sent` from the `sales_shipment` table:

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Exception;

class AddDataToShipmentsGrid
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * AddDataToOrdersGrid constructor.
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface $customLogger
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $customLogger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->logger   = $customLogger;
    }

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $subject
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param $requestName
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
    {
        if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_shipment_grid_data_source') {
            return $collection;
        }
        if ($collection->getMainTable() !== $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_shipment_grid')) {
            return $collection;
        }
        try {
            $shipmentTable = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_shipment');
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['s' => $shipmentTable],
                's.increment_id = main_table.increment_id',
                ['email_sent','label_generated']
            );

        } catch (Exception $error) {
            // Do nothing in that case
            $this->logger->error($error->getMessage());
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: why didn't you use the `Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select` component for your column? do you have a special custom logic?

Comment: @DianaBotean I have a custom renderer for that column, which is not there in the image. It can be Sent or Not Sent and I was thinking to add a dropdown having those 2 options

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code as you show us. Since the data in the sales_shipment table are either 1 or null. I have used the source model like below:

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\ShipmentGrid\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class EmailSent implements ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' =>  1, 'label' => __('Sent')],
            ['value' =>  null, 'label' => __('Not Sent')]
        ];
    }
}
```

As with the grid file, like Diana mentions using the default Magento select ui component does seem to work right away.

I am using Magento 2.4.2. I suggest once you have confirmed with using the code from above, if you still have some issue, then your magento version will be then next step to check.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
            <column name="email_sent" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">\Mbs\ShipmentGrid\Model\Config\Source\EmailSent</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email Sent</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```

Update: I also put my code for you to verify, @jimmy, are you able to try this code as it is loading fine on my install.
https://bitbucket.org/hervebackstage/shipmentgrid/src/master/

Comment: hi @Herve I cannot be null. If I add the null value, the option is not even displayed in my dropdown. Maybe something was changed on Magento 2.4.2 But on 2.3.4 it will not work

Comment: thanks for the update, I don't have 2.3.3 installed here. But your approach is correct

Comment: I'm using CE 2.4.2 and that code doesn't work. The thing with null value is it will be empty, no value displayed to select